# Wait until loader element doesn't appear for 5 seconds

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, ui-testing, web-testing

I am trying to test an addon for Google Spreadsheets, but I have an issue with waiting until the loader disappears completely.

If you go to https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/ and create a new blank page, you can observe that there will be a yellow "Working" loader across the menu, which will appear and disappear multiple times.

I would like to wait until that element hasn't appeared for 5 seconds before continuing the testing. Thank you.

Comment: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/pausing-the-test.html

Answer (score 4):

You could use this snippet:

```
// wait for a selector to disappear
const loader = Selector('div.jfk-butterBar')
    .withText('Updating...');
await t
    .expect(loader.with({visibilityCheck: true}).exists)
    .notOk({timeout: 5000});
```